# Show multiple location marker on Google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, logic

How can we `openInfoWindowHtml` on google map while mouse over on PHP MySQL result as follows,

http://www.yelp.com/c/denver/health

This sites shows Information window on google map while mouse over on result title

Tried as following,

```
//<![CDATA[
var map;
var geocoder;
var markerArray = [];
function loadMap(params) {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40, -100), 4);
        map.setZoom(8);
        searchLocationsNear(params)
    }
}

function searchLocationsNear(params) {

    var data = JSON.parse(params);
    var lenght = data.length;
    var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
    for ( var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {

        // check lat and long available with data
        if (data[i].enough_for_map) {
            var name = data[i].name;
            var address = data[i].address;

            if (data[i].description)
                var description = data[i].description;

            var point = new GLatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);

            var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, description);

            map.addOverlay(marker);

            markerArray[i + 1] = marker;

            var el_index = $('service_name_' + i);

            if (el_index) {

                el_index.addEvent('mouseover', marker);

                // GEvent.addDomListener(el_index, 'mouseover', function() {
                // GEvent.trigger(markerArray[i], 'click');
                // });

            }

            bounds.extend(point);
        }
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
}

function createMarker(point, name, address, description) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/><p>' + description + '</p>' + address;
    GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

above map locations pointed from mysql result set.

```
<h2>
    <a id="service_name_1" href="/example/details/bookkeeper/191">Photographer</a> 
</h2>
<h2>
    <a id="service_name_2" href="/example/details/bookkeeper/192">Teacher</a> 
</h2>
<h2>
    <a id="service_name_3" href="/example/details/bookkeeper/193">Accountant</a> 
</h2>
```

Excepted result:
While mouseover on each `h2` should show corresponding location info on map.

Any suggestion will greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How far have you gotten?

In principle you could,

Put a standard 'click'-event listeners on the markers you've placed on the map which displays the custom infoWindow (a few different approaches/examples here: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html).

Have another listener for 'mouseover' on the li elements of the sidebar-list, which in turns triggers the click-event. (Here's how to trigger google map events: http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#event)

Comment: Why are you using API-2? Your question tag says API-3.

Comment: If I were you, I'd investigate the line ` el_index.addEvent('mouseover', marker);` and maybe replace it with something along the lines of `el_index.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { GEvent.trigger(markerArray[i], 'click')});

Comment: already tried as you mention but, always shows the last marker only :(